# Calling a google API json file and display it as html, no data retrieved but successfully called site

Tags: javascript, json

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=I-Removed-My-Api-For-Posting',
 dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
  console.log('success',data);
    drawTable(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }

}

function drawRow(rowData) {
   var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.routes.bounds.northeast.lat + "</td>"));
 
 
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Json to HTML</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css">
   
  </head>
<body>

<table id="personDataTable">


    <tr>
        <th>Lat</th>       
    </tr>
</table>

 
</body>
</html>
```

```
    {
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJa147K9HX3IAR-lwiGIQv9i4",
     "types" : [ "amusement_park", "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
  },
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJzzgyJU--woARcZqceSdQ3dM",
     "types" : [ "amusement_park", "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
  }
   ],
   "routes" : [
  {
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 34.1373841,
           "lng" : -117.9220826
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 33.8151707,
           "lng" : -118.3575585
        }
     },
```

There is no CORS issue and I have successfully called the website after editing the url with my own API key. For the console log, I received success {geocoded_waypoints: Array(2), routes: Array(1), status: "OK"} , is there any way for me to retrieve the lat and lng from the json code please? I have been trying different methods but none of them work for me. What Is wrong with my code? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to interpret and iterate over the given data in the wrong manner.

**I have changed `data` to `data.routes` in `drawTable` function**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=I-Removed-My-Api-For-Posting',
    dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
  console.log('success',data);
    drawTable(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.routes.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data.routes[i]);
    }

}

function drawRow(routes) {
   var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + routes.bounds.northeast.lat + "</td>"));
}
```

**Additional interesting readings:**

https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

https://www.elated.com/articles/manipulating-javascript-arrays/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-arrays-in-javascript

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=working+with+arrays+in+javascript

Comment: if I were to call another array that is an array of routes, do I just change data.routes to data.routes.(array-name)?

Comment: Nope, do `data.routes[index].array_name` instead.

Comment: I tried to edit under function drawTable(data) to var I =0 , I <data.routes[index].array_name.length, it says index not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong because `rowData.routes` is an `array`.
You can get first routes by `rowData.routes[0].bounds.northeast.lat` or create loop on routes.

```
rowData.routes.forEach(function(route) {
    row.append($("<td>" + route.bounds.northeast.lat + "</td>"));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean this?

  '  function drawRow(rowData) {
       var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
 rowData.routes.forEach(function(route) {
    row.append($("<td>" + route.bounds.northeast.lat + "</td>"));
 }
 
}'

Comment: @Berwyn you can use either approach, Daremachine's approach is also right.

Comment: @Berwyn no matter what you want to use but you ask and point is your code work with object not with array routes are array. My sample is only give you idea how deal with it. GL